# OpenSSL C#.NET Wrapper X509 in a readable Format

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, x509certificate

Iam using the C#.NET Wrapper of OpenSSL and i try to generate an X509 certification in a readable form.
I can create an x509 certificate using

```
X509Certificate x509 = new X509Certificate(int serial,
        X509Name subject,
        X509Name issuer,
        CryptoKey pubkey,
        DateTime start,
        DateTime end)
```

Then I used x509.PEM to save it in a PEM Format but I want to save it in a readable way like this for example:

Certificate:

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 1234 (0x4d2)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: CN=Root
    Validity
        Not Before: May 13 18:59:46 2009 GMT
        Not After : May 13 18:59:46 2010 GMT
    Subject: CN=Root
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
        RSA Public Key: (4096 bit)
            Modulus (4096 bit):
                00:b2:ed:1d:e9:8a:56:80:a8:d4:d8:ca:da:e7:d0:
                66:75:66:df:3c:2a:7d:79:d7:62:d7:3e:69:a0:d9:
                3e:46:fd:e2:55:a7:18:58:81:bd:79:49:ae:37:de:
                28:17:a7:0d:e4:1b:f1:d6:69:b5:5e:ce:30:02:74:
```

...(I deleted the rest for a clear message)

How can I make it ? thanks for any help =)

Comment: The `X509Certificate` class seems to have a `ToString()` that might do what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh yeah i taught it's not implemented or it should be made in a standard way thx a lot ^^

Comment: @WOlF X509Certificate ToString() format is a bit different from openssl format. How did you get this in the same format?